# problems with import matplotlib in python3.6

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm trying to learn a project related to road_lane_line_detection. However,  other dependencies except "matplotlib" have already installed successfully, include: numpy, opencv-python, moviepy.

here is the recording:

```
(hqs0) ForddeMacBook-Pro:~ Ford$ pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in ./hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in ./hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in ./hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in ./hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in ./hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in ./hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
(hqs0) ForddeMacBook-Pro:~ Ford$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr  4 2017, 09:36:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import cv2
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Ford/hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1182, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "/Users/Ford/hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1025, in rc_params
    return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/Users/Ford/hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1151, in rc_params_from_file
    config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/Users/Ford/hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1068, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/Ford/hqs0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1053, in _open_file_or_url
    with io.open(fname, encoding=encoding) as f:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/Ford/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc'
>>>
```

I am not sure why it cause this problem, and thanks for your help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matplotlib uses a file called `matplotlibrc` to store configuration defaults.  If this file exists, then the setup script will try to read it.  The error is telling you that `/Users/Ford/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` does exist, but is a directory rather than a file, which is confusing the setup script.

You can probably fix this problem by removing the `matplotlibrc` directory, but be careful that there aren't any important files in there.  To be safe, you could rename it to something else:

```
mv /Users/Ford/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc /Users/Ford/.matplotlib/matploblirc_old
```

Comment: Thank you, it help me a lot.